# Can I create column which combain data from 2 other columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say that I have column 'name' and 'surename' both are varchar
I want to create column x which would be 'name + surename' and export data from columns 'name' & 'surename' into x. How can I do it?

Comment: Does a concatenated select solve your problem or do you need to actually have a new column (duplicating the data)? The column must be automatically updated when the name and surname is changed?

Comment: Take a look at generated columns.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html

Comment: Or use a [view](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html)

Answer (score 1):

As commented by Barmar, you can just use a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) for that:

```
alter table mytable 
add column full_name varchar(100) 
generated always as (concat(name, ' ', surname))
```

As explained in the documentation:

> Values of a generated column are computed from an expression included in the column definition.

So this gives you an always up-to-date value, whose initialization or maintenance you don't need to worry about.